# iOS Dropbox get thumbnails images

Tags: ios, swift, thumbnails, dropbox

I'm trying to load thumbnails images of a Dropbox account, but I got a bug. I create a local directory in the first method to put thumbnails, and I make a request to load them, but it doesn't works.

Here is my code :

```
// Create directory method 
func createTempDirectory() -> String? {

    let tempDirectoryTemplate = NSTemporaryDirectory()
    tempDirectoryTemplate.stringByAppendingPathComponent("XXXXX")

    let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()

    var err: NSErrorPointer = nil
    if fileManager.createDirectoryAtPath(tempDirectoryTemplate, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil, error: err) {
        return tempDirectoryTemplate
    }
    else {
        return nil
    }
}

// Get thumbnails images 
func restClient(client: DBRestClient!, loadedMetadata metadata: DBMetadata!) {

    temporaryDirectory = createTempDirectory()!

    for file in metadata.contents {
        if (file.thumbnailExists == true) {
            client.loadThumbnail(file.path, ofSize: "s", intoPath: temporaryDirectory)
        }
    }

    self.collectionView?.reloadData()
}
```

And this is the error :

```
[WARNING] DropboxSDK: error making request to /1/thumbnails/dropbox/star.jpg - (4) Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 4.)
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Can you implement and post your `loadedThumbnail` and `loadThumbnailFailedWithError` (be sure to include some logging, e.g., of the error in the latter) as well as the corresponding output? It also would be good to log out the value of `temporaryDirectory`, since error code 4 in `NSCocoaErrorDomain` is `NSFileNoSuchFileError`, per the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Constants/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/NSError_Codes).

Comment: Oh, also, I believe `intoPath` is supposed to be given the full path where you want to store the resulting thumbnail file, including file name, not just a folder.

Comment: What does this have to do with objective-c?